# How to use Webhooks in rundeck to send status of the job executed

Tags: html-email, webhooks, rundeck

Completely new to Webhook concept and Rundeck. I have a job in rundeck where it checkes health of some servers, code being in python.

[Fetch 200 Ok status after running Curl Command and using that status write a condition using python in RUNDECK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61952749/fetch-200-ok-status-after-running-curl-command-and-using-that-status-write-a-con)

i want to use webhook to provide update via email/slack channel to 5-6 users

Created a webhook, i selected a job which it should invoke, but i didnt understand what options to be entered options section[Job Option arguments, in the form `-opt1 value -opt2 "other value"`]

when i click on the webhook URL it gives 404 error found.

this might be the very basic questions. sorry kindly help

Answer (score 1):

> i want to use webhook to provide update via email/slack channel to 5-6 users

Webhooks are used to enable third-party applications to trigger jobs. If you just want to send notifications of job status when a job is run, you don't need to use a webhook.

When you configure the job there's a "Notifications" tab. You can select when and how to send notifications. For slack specifically, there is a [notification plugin](https://github.com/rundeck-plugins/pagerduty-notification/) you can install.

Answer (score 0):

To pass options to webhook you need to pass it in this [way](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60400477/10426011). [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63359601/10426011) you have a good example to integrate it with python code.

UPDATE: Anyway, this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63385980/10426011) is the way to achieve your goal.